# Debug Android application on Firefox

Tags: android, cordova, debugging, firefox

I'm currently using Firefox Developer Edition as my default browser (especially at work). The problem is that didn't find a way to debug my applications on it, on chrome I just go to chrome://inspect and there it is. On Firefox's Web IDE I find my device but it only show me the webpages I have open, not the app.
These applications I'm referring to are built on top of Cordova using JS, HTML and CSS.

Is there a way to do it Gecko/Firefox or just on chromium based browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FF Web IDE is only made to debug Web or Firefox OS apps. You cannot debug a Cordova app from FF. You need Chrome.